# How to prevent the software like Fiddler from intercepting requests and intercepting requests sent out in electron

Tags: request, electron, web-crawler, fiddler

From the request made in electron, I don't want the software like Fiddler to see how it should be done. Any help is very grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Such information is ultimately public (if the traffic is not encrypted by HTTPS, but Fiddler can also read this because it acts as a man in the middle), and there is even more sophisticated software, like Wireshark which lets you read *any* network traffic which is flowing through your LAN.

In case you are not using HTTPS: Use HTTPS with valid, non-self-signed certificates (like the free Let's Encrypt certificates) and enable certificate checking in Electron if you have it disabled (it's enabled by default) because Electron will then reject the self-signed certificate Fiddler uses for HTTPS traffic and thus will not make any request, which ultimately prevents Fiddler from reading them.

However, I would not bother about this issue at all. Anyone with access to the connection can sniff on it and even on HTTPS traffic if all secrets are accessible (i.e. the one sniffing sits on the same system or has access to it), so there really is no way to keep request/response information "secret" with some third party having access to all the secret stuff.